# Can the coordinator be found or identified?

Tags: security

The coordinator is currently vital to the operation of the Iota network. There are both security (leaking the seed used to generate milestones) and availability (it must be able to issue milestones) impacts if it were to be attacked.

Most attacks against the coordinator would require that the IP address is known. This isn't an open or documented property.

Is it possible for an adversary to find the coordinator?

Comment: Naming a few attacks would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see the relevance, it's immaterial to the question. Happy to ask another question.

Comment: It wasn't clear if you envisioned a coordinator connected to the Internet or one hidden behind NAT. Without that it was unclear which IP address you meant.